# ITextSharp build phrase from Html with list tags

Tags: c#, itext

I have a report that I'm trying to generate using iTextSharp that includes html text entered by the user using tinymce on my web page.  I then have a report and I want to insert a phrase that uses their markup.

While basic markup such as bold and underline work, lists, indents, alignment do not.  Any suggestions short of writing my own little html to pdf parser?

My code:

```
internal static Phrase GetPhraseFromHtml(string html, string fontName, int fontSize)
{
    var returnPhrase = new Phrase();
    html.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty);

    //the string has to be well formated html in order to work and has to specify the font since
    //specifying the font in the phrase overrides the formatting of the html tags.
    string pTag = string.Format("<p style='font-size: {0}; font-family:{1}'>", fontSize, fontName);
    if (html.StartsWith("<p>"))
    {
        html = html.Replace("<p>", pTag);
    }
    else
    {
        html = pTag + html + "</p>";
    }
    html
        = "<html><body>"
        + html
        + "</body></html>";

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            var xmlWorkerHandler = new XmlWorkerHandler();
            //Bind a reader to our text
            using (TextReader textReader = new StringReader(html))
            {
                //Parse
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(xmlWorkerHandler, textReader);
            }
            var addPhrase = new Phrase();

            var elementText = new StringBuilder();
            bool firstElement = true;

            //Loop through each element
            foreach (var element in xmlWorkerHandler.elements)
            {
                if (firstElement)
                {
                    firstElement = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    addPhrase.Add(new Chunk("\n"));
                }

                //Loop through each chunk in each element
                foreach (var chunk in element.Chunks)
                {
                    addPhrase.Add(chunk);
                }

                returnPhrase.Add(addPhrase);
                addPhrase = new Phrase();
            }
            return returnPhrase;
        }
    }
}
```